# Magento 2: Customer session not getting on enabling cache in backend

Tags: magento2, customer, xml, customer-session

This is my XML file.

```
<referenceBlock name="category.products.list">
  <action method="setTemplate">
    <argument name="template" xsi:type="string" cacheable="false">Company_Module::product/list.phtml</argument>
  </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

In the **`list.phtml`** file.

I have displayed a pop-up on the basis of customer session value (customer logged in/not). On enabling cache in the backend, I am not getting customer session value (customer logged in) hence pop up is not coming. The module is working fine if a cache is disabled. How can we set `cacheable=false` for overwritten template files in XML?

Comment: Please give me a solution.Thanks in advace